# How to know what date a particular day has using C language

Tags: c

Print last wednesday of February 2020 in the format yyyy/mm/dd.
Given examples of a meetup dates, each containing a month, day, year, and descriptor calculate the date of the actual meetup. For example, if given "The first Monday of January 2017", the correct meetup date is 2017/1/2.

This is the code which I have tried and I am now blank what to do next.Please help me whether my concept is correct or is there any other way to solve this question?

The descriptors you are expected to parse are: first, second, third, fourth, fifth, last, monteenth, tuesteenth, wednesteenth, thursteenth, friteenth, saturteenth, sunteenth

Note that "monteenth", "tuesteenth", etc are all made up words. There was a meetup whose members realized that there are exactly 7 numbered days in a month that end in '-teenth'. Therefore, one is guaranteed that each day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, ...) will have exactly one date that is named with '-teenth' in every month.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int search_date(char str[100])
{
    char str1[100],*sub1;
    char dilem[]=" ";
    strcpy(str1,str);
    sub1 = strtok(str1,dilem);//the concept here for using strtok is to get every word of the string seperately and match it with the prescribed words
    while(sub1 != NULL)
 {
     if (sub1=="first" || sub1=="second" || sub1=="third" || sub1=="fourth" || sub1=="fifth" || sub1=="last" || sub1=="monteenth" || sub1=="tuesteenth" || sub1=="wednesteenth" || sub1=="thursteenth" || sub1=="friteenth" || sub1=="saturteenth" || sub1=="sunteenth")
     {
      find_day();
     }
     else if(sub1=="January" || sub1=="February" || sub1=="March" || sub1=="April" || sub1=="May" || sub1=="June" || sub1=="July" || sub1=="August" || sub1=="September" || sub1=="October" || sub1=="November" || sub1=="December")
      {
          find_month();
      }
      
}
int find_day(char *sub1)
{
    //in this section I am totally blank how to get the day number.Please guide me
}
int find_month(char *sub1)
{
    //Here using case or if else I can get the month number
}
int find_year(char *str)
{
    int y;
    char *p = strrchr(str, ' ');
if (p && *(p + 1))
{
    sscanf(p+1,"%d",&y);//from this I have got the year in the variable y
}
}
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter the string:");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",str);
    find_year(str);
    search_date(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C (don't know about C++) compare strings with `strcmp()` ... this is wrong `if (sub1 == "first")`

Comment: If you don't have a concrete issue you need help with, then I think that https://codereview.stackexchange.com will be more appropriate for this post.

Comment: @MarkLoyman Only if the missing code is provided. It would be closed if posted as-is.

Comment: as said by @pmg `sub1=="first"` must be `!strcmp(sub1,"first")` and same for other string comparisons using ==. Also in `while(sub1 != NULL){...}` *sub1* is unchanged, typically you want `while(sub1 != NULL){..., sub1 = strtok(NULL,dilem);}`.